# Is it immoral to withhold the truth about a patients health outcome

Tags: ethics

Say, for example, a doctor knows that a patient will die very soon and the doctor knows with either absolute certainty or slight uncertainity, that this will be very traumatic for the patient to find out; is it immoral for the doctor to still withhold this information? That is, are there ways to determine the morality aside from weighing up the decision in a utilitarian way or is there any principle that states that telling the truth take precedence?

Thanks

Comment: Are there choices that would be canceled by not knowing? (Saying goodbye, making a will, last chance to do a thing, etc.) Are there family or loved-ones involved who would want to know?  I'd be surprised if a hospital, medical association, etc., didn't already have policy on such issues.

Comment: Yes, I only thought about accouting for those other costs/benefits through utilitarianism. I was wondering if there was a different principle to follow here?

Comment: Too vague. To be more direct is better. If I specifically ask the doctor to tell me the truth to his best abilities then he is morally obligated to tell me the truth as he knows it. Withholding the truth would be immoral because truth was asked for & the doctor betrayed my trust. This is based on principles only not actions. Utilitarianism is a pseudo moral theory. With it there are a million or more variables to consider & seems like people reason from convenience or the scenario benefits them. Too many answers to the same question means the method is not reliable. It is now probability.